# Opcodes to load generic object as argument

Tags: c#, reflection, typebuilder

I am calling a method where one of the arguments is of type object. How do I load that on the stack? I know enums have integer equivalents but I'd also like to use this to put actual objects created with Type.CreateInstance as arguments to method addoutput

```
//method addoutput of type overriden by the typebuilder is of form    addoutput(object o)
//enumType is a Type that is an enumeration
TypeBuilder tb;
//tb is initialized here
//override constructor
ConstructorBuilder ctor1 = tb.DefineConstructor(MethodAttributes.Public,    CallingConventions.Standard, null);
ILGenerator ctor1IL = ctor1.GetILGenerator();
FieldInfo[] infos;
infos = enumType.GetFields(BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Static);
//basically for each value in the enumeration an output is created
foreach (FieldInfo fi in infos)
{
 MethodInfo addoutputinfo = tb.BaseType.GetMethod("addoutput",     BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance |     BindingFlags.Static);
 ctor1IL.Emit(OpCodes.Ldarg_0);
 //something like this ? seems there's a syntax error 
 ctor1IL.Emit(OpCodes.Ldobj,fi.GetValue(null))  
 ctor1IL.Emit(OpCodes.Call, addoutputinfo);
}
```

Comment: Can you please provide a [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)?

Comment: ok, please review OP again , thanks

Comment: Write the code in C# then look at what is generated in ILDASM.  https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f7dy01k1(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: @user1296193, can you provide c# equivalent what you try get?

Comment: addoutput(Enum.EnumValue1);   addoutput(Enum.EnumValue2); ....

Comment: What is the signature of your "addoutput" method?